# Selenium cant find element with xpath or ClassName or Css Selector (Python)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

Hello I am trying to click The no thanks button on google look : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucHRs.png)

The full element of the button is this

```
<button aria-label="No thanks" class="M6CB1c rr4y5c" jsname="ZUkOIc" jslog="71121; track:click;" data-dismiss="n">No thanks</button>
```

I tried to select it with the xpath like this
EDIT: I have a wait element up in the code here `Wait = WebDriverWait(driver,60)`

```
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")

Wait = WebDriverWait(driver,60)

buttonSignIn = "//button[@class='M6CB1c rr4y5c'][1]/@class"

Wait.until(EC.visibility_of_any_elements_located((By.XPATH,buttonSignIn)))

buttonSign = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,buttonSignIn)

print(buttonSign.get_attribute("innerHTML"))
```

I also before tried to select it with Css like this

```
buttonSignIn = ".M6CB1c.rr4y5c"

Wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,buttonSignIn)))

buttonSign = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,buttonSignIn)

print(buttonSign.get_attribute("innerHTML"))
```

I also tried to select it with Class Name like this

```
buttonSignIn = "M6CB1c rr4y5c"

Wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME,buttonSignIn)))

buttonSign = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,buttonSignIn)

print(buttonSign.get_attribute("innerHTML"))
```

I followed the other stuff from stack overflow that had my problem. WHat am i doing wrong

Comment: You have to wait for element to become visible for Selenium first, so just wait and timeout after 10 seconds. (While selector is None)

Comment: yes i have a wait element up in the code look Wait = WebDriverWait(driver,60)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element is inside an `iframe`, In order to reach the element, you need to switch to iframe first.

Use `WebDriverWait()` and wait for `frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it()`
Then `WebDriverWait()` and wait for `element_to_be_clickable()`. you can use below `css selector` to uniquely identify the element.

```
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "iframe[name='callout']")))
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.M6CB1c.rr4y5c"))).click()
```

Import below libraries.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
```

Comment: didnt work here is my whole code

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/user/therookiedev/comments/11zt276/temp/

Comment: i did copy and paste it it didnt work fine

Comment: @theonedeveloper, what error are you getting?

Comment: timeout error sir :) ill paste it

Comment: here is error https://www.reddit.com/user/therookiedev/comments/11ztm1h/error/

Comment: can you remove the `chrome option` and check, It seems you have disabled the notification.

Comment: still timeout error I will edit this comment with code one seccond :) https://www.reddit.com/user/therookiedev/comments/11zts3f/code_2/

Comment: code is there sir :) @KunduK

Comment: Got the issue. If you see attribute values it is different Showing it to you and me. Try the updated on.

Comment: Now this should also work. `WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[aria-label='No thanks']"))).click()`